# How to properly structure routes in react.js using nested routes along with private route component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I am using react-router-dom. Currently i have an app.js file with routhing something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">

        <Header/>

        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route path='/profile' component={Profile}/>
        </Switch>

    </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

So, I have header component which is always on the page, and routing for two components, dashboard and profile. Now, i want to add new page "Login" that will only have a login component (without header component). Something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">

        <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>

            <Route path='/'>

                <Header/>

                 <Switch>
                     <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
                     <Route path='/profile' component={Profile}/>
                 </Switch>

            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

And the final step would be to replace route component with private route component.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by private route? 
For the login page with no header use React fragments

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/login' component={LoginComponent} /> {/* <--- No header */}
    <Fragment>
        <Header/>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route path='/profile' component={Profile}/>
    </Fragment>
</Switch>
```

Comment: thanks, but i needed to wrap thoes two routes inside fragment into one more switch to for this to work as expected. Is there any smoother way of doing this?